# How to make a script passing his PID to another running script

Tags: 12.04, bash

i have a script which is the main one and this script open a new terminal and execute another script so what i want is to pass the PID of the second script to the first script

the main script

```
#!/bin/bash 

gnome-terminal -e "/home/......./script.sh"
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
PID= $$
```

i want to pass the variable called PID to the main script

REGARDS

Comment: beware, in shell variable assignment, you *must not* put spaces around the "=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get print the PID by doing this

the main script

```
#!/bin/bash 

gnome-terminal -e "/home/......./script.sh" &
PID=$!
echo "child_PID="$PID
```

Note that you will may get the PID of the gnome-terminal and not the script itself.

If you want the PID of the `/home/..../script.sh` run it directly without `gnome-terminal`:

```
#!/bin/bash 

/home/......./script.sh &
PID=$!
echo "child_PID="$PID
```

A question: Do you really need to run the script through `gnome-terminal`?

**EDIT**: The `script.sh` now runs in background ( with `&` ) and we're echoing the child PID.

Comment: yes i do actually i had too :)

Comment: did u try it urself ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it myself. Maybe you are missing and echo on PID or what you really want is that the process runs in background (&). I'll update the answer to make those clear.

Comment: Please try with the changes I made and tell me if it works.

Comment: one more question , if i dont put this & in case i dont want to run it in back ground the $! wont work and give me its id ?

Comment: Yep, was my mistake at the first time. There's no point in getting the pid of process that has already finished. If you don't put the `&` at the end of `/home/../script.sh`, the next line after the command will only be executed when the `script.sh` ends, so the pid won't exist anymore when `PID=$!` runs

Comment: YES BUT TELL ME PLS , IN CASE I MADE IT LIKE THIS `gnome-terminal "/.../script.sh &"` it will still run in terminal window and if i closed it by my self i will close the scrip.sh or the terminal window wont be visible for me ?

Comment: If you think the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted. If you truthfully liked the answer you can also vote up for it.